# Django - inheritance

Tags: django, django-models, django-errors, django-inheritance

I have a problem with inheritance :

```
class ContainPj(models.Model):
    id_scribe=models.IntegerField()
    id_pj=models.IntegerField()

    class Meta :
        abstract = True


class Member(ContainPj):
    pass


class Collab(Member):
    pass
```

I make :
    m = Member(id_scribe=..., id_pj=...)
    c = Collab(m)
    c.save()
and thither :
**TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Member'**

I don't understand... and I research on the web and I haven't found one solution...

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Why are you trying to instantiate the `Collab` object with a `Member` ? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: I want Collab haves the same attributes than Member but I want to search all member (Collab also) and I want to searh just Collab...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to populate `Collab` fields from `Member` instance then you should do it explicitly:

```
c = Collab(id_scribe=m.id_scribe, id_pj=m.id_pj)
```